# Until what version back of all majors broswer do you support when developing a website as of 2013?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I am trying to develop rich and modern websites but this means extra work for the older broswers.

**Until what version back of all majors broswer should i consider supporting as of 2013 ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gecko- and webkit-based browsers are typically less problematic, so it mostly breaks down to which versions of IE you want to support...

Based on the various IE countdown sites:

http://www.ie6countdown.com

http://theie7countdown.com

http://theie8countdown.com

... it's reasonable to ignore IE6, unless you're targeting China (where many banks require it to log in). It's also reasonable to ignore IE7. It's not very reasonable to ignore IE8, unless you know your audience isn't using it.

(Another good proxy is which browsers major sites Facebook and Youtube support. Incidentally, they both dropped IE6 support.)

Answer (score 2):

It is not about which year you are developing an application, it is about your audience. I work in the construction industry and there are heaps of people, most likely trades men, still using IE6 and IE7. Some of them called our support team but could not even do 'copy and paste' tasks.

If your audiences are young. I  believe you can ignore IE6, IE7. The pain is always IE. for other browsers, it is much less a problem. You can try out Bootstrap or some other frameworks, they provide a very good foundation for a 'modern' website.

Understanding the audience is not only critical to a successful website, but also to the whole business.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question with one simple answer. It's much more complicated than that. I think you'll be better of deciding which features to put in by checking the browser support of that individual feature. This is one of the websites you can use for this:

http://caniuse.com/

or this

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Also, the usage of brosers depends on many factor, geography being one of them. You can check the wikipedia page which will also tell you about the various web statistics monitoring websites for comparison.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

Comment: I know people are skeptical about w3schools but this is a much simpler issue. I think it is fairly useful if you are checking compatibility of CSS3 features.

Comment: In case it helps, I personally like caniuse.com when it comes to checking what's supported by each browser